# c++, WMI API returns VT_NULL, wmic returns VT_BSTR on Windows XP

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi, wmic

I'm using the following snippet in C++ to query [Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WQL:

```
[ cut WMI init part, initialize security and stuff ]

IWbemClassObject* clsObj = NULL;
int numElems;
while((hRes = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &clsObj, (ULONG*)&numElems)) != WBEM_S_FALSE)  
 {  

  VARIANT vRet;  
  VariantInit(&vRet); 

      if(SUCCEEDED(clsObj->Get(LPCWSTR("HostAddress"), 0, &vRet, NULL, NULL)))  
        {
           printf("HostAddress VT: %d", vRet.vt);
        }

      VariantClear(&vRet);

} 

clsObj->Release();

[...]
```

(Error checks and initializations have been removed for the posting)

Above code works in Windows 7 without any issues and returns the correct `VT_BSTR`. 
But Windows XP gives a `VT_NULL` instead of `VT_BSTR` for `clsObj->Get(...`

If you do a

`wmic -U user%pass //WINXPHOST "SELECT HostAddress FROM Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort"`

call from another (Linux obviously) machine on the network it returns all values just fine.

I also tried `cscript prnport.vbs -l -s WINXPHOST` which told me the correct values.

[--- EDIT ---]

Interesting, I took the default C++ WMI MSDN example from here: [Example: Getting WMI Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I changed the WQL to `bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort"),`
and in `Step 7` to

```
// Get the value of the HostAddress property
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"HostAddress", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
wcout << " HostAddress : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

When compiled, it runs and returns a `VT_BSTR` on Windows 7 machines, `VT_NULL` on Windows XP machines.

Could be a bug?
Thoughts?

Comment: Your casts are troublesome.  You'll get away with the ULONG cast, not the LPCWSTR cast.  Use `L"HostAddress"` instead.

Comment: Well `LPCWSTR` is just an example, in the real program I read an XML file, get the Columns for the WQL from there and iterate through that then. I'm then converting std::string to LPCWSTR using `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: Did the test with `L"HostAddress"` - issue is still the same, returns `VT_NULL`

Comment: Maybe check more precisely the return value of Get? I guess VT_NULL is here since the VariantInit call.

Comment: good idea @manuell - did that and on both machines (win7+winxp) the return value for `hr = pclsObj->Get(...` is `0`.

Comment: You could run wbemtest to verify that it's not an issue with your code.

Comment: `wbemtest` returns `Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort=<no key>` - so I guess it's an issue with the API.